# How can i add html tags to option

Tags: php, html

How can i add `<i></i>` to inside `<option></option>`?

I have this code

```
<option value="<?= $pages->ID ?>"><i class="<?=$icon?>"></i><?php echo get_the_title($allPages[$key]) ?> left</option>
```

But `<i></i>` is not displayed.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: So that the icon can be displayed in <option>

Answer (score -2):

You can achieve it by using font icon code.

See ref here `jsfiddle.net/14606fv9/2/`

Comment: i have wordpress dashicons, how worked <i class="dashicons dashicons-admin-site">